# Why does this javascript Type error occur when I change the location of the library?

Tags: javascript, browser, vis.js

I'm puzzled by this error at the moment:

I have transferred [this](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/data/dynamicFiltering.html) visjs example html file to a directory on my machine. When I set line 7 to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>`

and open in a browser, it works fine. But when I also copy [the library](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js) locally, changing line 7 to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/vis-network.min.js"></script>`

and reference that, it fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: t.forEach is not a function
```

I can't work out why this error is occurring. It happens both in Firefox and Chrome.

- **Is this error repeatable for anyone else?**
- **Why is this happening?**
- **Is there something obvious I'm missing?**
- **What debugging steps would you take?**

Comment: Could you view the source and see if the lib is loaded or not .

Comment: @Sohail yes appears to be loaded

Comment: @Sohail when I corrupt the library url I get a different error: `ReferenceError: vis is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a comically simple error!

The `-` in the file name meant that it was pointing to an older version of visjs.

I may delete this question, though perhaps it'll help someone one day. **If you get this error - check your file names**!